# Precedence of * and / in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I didnt get the logic behind the answer. I tried to print the value of a after definition and it shows a=72. Please help.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {
       int a=400*400/400;
       if(a==400)
       printf("Do good");
       else
       printf("Have good");
    }
```

output : Have Good

Comment: You should just make your test-case `printf("%d\n", a)`.

Comment: What is the `int` size on your platform?

Comment: C's precedence rules prescribe that `400*400/400` is equivalent to `(400*400)/400`. Unless your `MAXINT` is less than 160000, I think precedence isn't the problem here.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. I cannot reproduce this problem (Mac OS X 10.10) (simply assigned `400 * 400 / 400` to `a` and `printf("%d\n",a)`)

Comment: see http://ideone.com/DNnBGq for results on a 32/64 bits machine

Comment: @Arc676 Isn't this a SSCCE already? The problem is just that OP is missing easily missed information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that on your platform `int` is 2 byte wide, 16 bit.

Then

```
400*400 = 28928
```

Due to overflow

```
28928/400 = 72
```

Comment: Just a question: why isn't `400*400` promoted to a larger type like `long` and then **successfully** divided by `400` and **afterwards** truncated because the larger type doesn't fit into an `int`? Hope you understand what I mean. ^^

Comment: @cad because of on OP platform `int` is 16 bit, then integer promotion is not made on 32 bit `int`.

Comment: @cad: because that's not what C's rules require must happen.  Integer promotion only happens for integer types smaller than int promoting up to int.  Also, it would be weird if compile-time constants were special-cased, and promoted when expressions involving variables weren't.

Comment: @cad `400` has type `int`. Because both arguments to the `*` operator have the same integer type, no conversion is mandated by the standard. `400*400` again has type `int`. Again, both arguments to the `/` operator have the same type. The promotion *would* have taken place for `400L*400/400` and `400*400L/400`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are such special cases forbidden by the standard?

Comment: @Rhymoid: what, for compile-time constants to be treated differently?  I think so.  The wording in the standard just talks about expressions of whatever type, and gets pretty specific about exactly what the promotion rules are.  That's one reason for the modifier suffixes on constants.  e.g. 0xffffffffUL.  There are other suffixes for other types.

Comment: @PeterCordes That specificness kind of makes sense now that I think of it. I somehow thought that compilers were allowed to calculate constant expressions with arbitrary precision (with minimal limits) and worry about machine types later, but now that I put that to words, it already doesn't make sense: the compiler would have to consider types anyway, to figure out whether `/` is integer division or float division.

Comment: @Rhymoid The types of all integer constants are well-defined in C, as are the implicit promotion rules (although they are a bit complex). When programming in C, it is the programmer's responsibility to know the data bus width of the CPU used and other such basics of CPU hardware.

Comment: Nice answer day! I'd like to point out that C was designed to be a *portable system language* for Unix, and indeed, if you stay in the realms of standard C (i.e. *refrain from reliance upon implementation-defined or undefined behaviour where possible*) you really *don't* need know any of that hardware-related information, @Lundin. It should be pointed out that signed integer overflows (i.e. `400 * 400` where `INT_MAX` is 32767) are squarely *undefined behaviour*, and so fall squarely *outside of the realms of C*.

Answer (score 4):

`400*400 = 160 000 = 18 bits.` 
If you convert this to 16 bits you get `28928`.

```
28928 / 400 = 72,32
```

Comment: So the OP has a 16-bit `int` size.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers didn't address the title of the question:
`*` and `/` are the same precedence rank, with left-to-right associativity.  This means the 400*400 happens before the division.

A google search for Operator Precedence in C turns up http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence as the first hit.  Did you even try googling on the title of your question?

---

The other answers already did a good job explaining the `72` is due to `int` being 16bit on your platform.  You could use `400UL * 400 / 400` to have the result computed with `unsigned long`, or `ULL` for `unsigned long long`, since `unsigned long` is required to be at least 32bit.

The other way to avoid the integer overflow here is to write it as `400 * (400/400)` so the division happens first.

Comment: 16bit long long would not be a legal C implementation under any C standard. C99 introduced the long long type and it specifies that the smallest possible `LONGLONG_MAX` is 2^63-1. Smallest possible `LONG_MAX` is 2^31-1 by the way.

Comment: If we ignore the size of integer literals and overflows in C, what makes you think that `(400*400)/400` would give a different result than `400*(400/400)`? Precedence doesn't matter in the slightest here.

Comment: @Art: oh right, I should have checked what the minimums were for long and long long.  Fixed.

Comment: @Lundin: We can't ignore overflow, because that's why the OP is getting 72 instead of 400.  `400*(400/400) = 400*1 = 400` won't overflow even with 16bit integers.  The *title* of the question is "Precedence of * and / in C", and I felt that part of the question was unanswered by the other answers.

Comment: Ah my bad, didn't see that it was actually what the OP asked for, even though it isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Lundin: It actually *is* the cause of the problem, if the OP expected the 400/400 to cancel out first.  Or the solution, with parentheses.  But yeah, I suspect the downvoters didn't realize that was the title either.